# How to add Loading overlay android application

Tags: android, android-activity, overlay

everyone.

I have a custom loading that i am showing above my activity.

That's OK and it works fine , but i need to do one thing here.(Bit Complicated for me.)

Here how can i make my background page (View) scroll-able and loading will still be there.?

In Short..Loading over scroll-able activity.

Here is my already implemented code , for Showing Transparent Loading.

```
public class TransparentProgressDialog extends Dialog {

private ImageView iv;
private TextView tv;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public TransparentProgressDialog(Context context, int resourceIdOfImage) {
    super(context, R.style.Theme_Transparent);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        wlmp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp);
    setTitle(null);
    setCancelable(false);
    setOnCancelListener(null);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable((context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_view_rounded_single)));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    iv = new ImageView(context);
    iv.setImageResource(resourceIdOfImage);
    tv= new TextView(context);
    tv.setText("Loading...");
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    tv.setTextSize(18f);
    tv.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    layout.addView(tv, params);
    layout.addView(iv, params);
    addContentView(layout, params);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();
    RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setDuration(2000);
    iv.setAnimation(anim);
    iv.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

}

Comment: Well, first, loading dialog is discouraged by the Android design pattern, instead you should show a loader where the content will appear. Still in your case, how would you be able to scroll if you have the loading animation at the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

You can change dialog to fragment. In root of xml fragment layout add this line:

`android:clickable="false"`